# How to switch over from a XML DB to MySQL Table while dealing with Java Classes

Tags: java, mysql, xml

Long time lurker with finding answers to my questions here, but this one has me stumped.

I have a system programmed in Java which uses a XML DB and want to convert it to a MySQL Table.  Converting over is not the issue, but rather of how to keep the Java Classes intact afterwards.

For example (example code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
  <object class="server.objects.Pets">
    <void property=\"petInfo\">
      <void property=\"general\">
        <void method=\"put\">
          <object class=\"server.objects.GeneralData\">
            <void property=\"Name\">
              <string>Mikey</string>
            </void>
            <void property=\"Breed\">
              <string>Mutt</string>
            </void>
            <void property=\"Gender\">
              <string>Male</string>
            </void>
          </object>
        </void>
      </void>
    </void>
  </object>
</java>
```

And from that, I am going to make the Name, Breed and Gender into Columns.
But my problem that I have difficulty with is of how to associate those Classes, such as Pets and GeneralData, with the MySQL Columns.

With the XML Setup, there is a decoder which uses getClass and getClassLoader.
Unfortunately my Java skills are not great, which is why I am asking this.

So, what would be the Java statements after making a SQL Query, as with SELECT, to associate the Classes with the Data from the Columns?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: The code didn't show up... one moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a ORM solution such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or any [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) solution like [Open JPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) or [Eclipse Link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/). If this is to much of learning you can go with JDBC access using plain SQL and map those to Java instances using [Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

There are other solutions but basically utilizing a JPA ORM solution is the way to go.

Comment: I'll have to keep those in mind, as that will take some rework with the system, which is currently using JDBC. May be good to do for a future upgrade version.  

So ok then, go with the DAO.Which if I am correct, would be to perform a query, and from the query then associate/map those classes to the columns.  

And thanks for the quick response!